# JavaMail doesn't download full csv file attachment

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, mime

I am having an issue with downloading csv file attachments from Gmail. All the settings/preferences seem to work fine. The plugin will download most of the file without issue, in fact the program doesn't produce any errors but it is cutting off the last line of the file and partially from the second to last line.
Can anyone see an issue in my code that would point to why this is happening?

Edit: Updated code to reflect for loop changes.

Edit2: Is there an overflow or buffer size I need to be worried about? The size of the files I will be downloading aren't very big. They are csv files with at least 140 lines in them.

```
public void searchEmailByID (int emailID) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    //server setting
    properties.put("mail.imap.host", GmailHost);
    properties.put("mail.imap.port", GmailPort);

    //SSL setting
    properties.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    properties.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    properties.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.port", String.valueOf(GmailPort));

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

    try {
        //connects to message store
        Store store = session.getStore("imap");
        store.connect(GmailUser, GmailPassword);

        //opens the inbox folder
        Folder folderInbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
        folderInbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

        //creates the search criteria
        SearchTerm searchCondition = new SearchTerm() {
            @Override
            public boolean match(Message message) {
                try {
                    if (message.getMessageNumber() == emailID) {
                        return true;
                    }
                } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Null exception at line 50, may be due to variation in timing");
                    //ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                return false;
            }
        };

        //performs search through the folder
        Message[] foundMessages = folderInbox.search(searchCondition);
        setRecentlySearchMsg(foundMessages[0]);

        for (int i = 0; i < foundMessages.length; i++) {
            Message message = foundMessages[i];
            String subject = message.getSubject(); //subject in the target email
            Date date = message.getReceivedDate(); //date the email was received
            System.out.println("Found message #" + i + ": " + subject + ", Date Received: " + date.toString());
            String contentType = message.getContentType();
            System.out.println("Content type: " + contentType);
            Multipart multipart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
            int count = 0;  //count object to ensure overflows aren't triggered
            for (int j = 0; j < multipart.getCount(); j++) {
                MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multipart.getBodyPart(j); //using the i loop to establish connection to message
                if(part.getContentType().contains("TEXT/PLAIN")) {
                    continue;
                } else if(part.getContentType().contains("TEXT/HTML")) {
                    break;
                }
                if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
                    String dateToday = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").format(new Date());   //Retrieving today's date
                    String path = "/file/location/here/" + dateToday + "_" + part.getFileName();
                    if(part.getFileName().contains("User")) {
                        userFileLocation = path;
                    } else if(part.getFileName().contains("Teams")) {
                        teamFileLocation = path;
                    }
                    part.saveFile(path);
                    System.out.println("File successfully saved in folder with name: " + path);
                    System.out.println("File is located at: " + path);
                    count++;
                }
                if (count == 2){
                    break;
                }

            }
        }

        //disconnect
        folderInbox.close(false);
        store.close();
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException ex) {
        System.out.println("No provider.");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
        System.out.println("Could not connect to the message store.");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error parsing message attachment");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: TL;DR `for (int j = 0; j < multipart.getCount(); i++) ` smells, this is probably `j++` ?

Comment: @PeterMmm Just updated the post to reflect the changes, I had made these before I uploaded. Code still produces the same result.